# adding i3lock to config file

Tags: configuration, debian, i3-wm

I want to created a shortcut for locking my screen. Normally I lock my screen by typing the following in the terminal

```
i3lock -c 000000
```

I try adding to my config file by doing following but nothing works

1. copy copy `/etc/i3/config` to `~/.i3/config`
2. `$ vim .i3/config`
3. scroll down and add following line to file: `bindsym Mod1+l i3lock -c 000000`. I also tried variants such as `bindsym Mod1+l exec i3lock -c 000000` and `bindsym Mod1+l exec "i3lock -c 000000"`
4. Save file
5. Reload i3 with `Mod1+Shift+R`
6. Try login out with shortcut `Mod1+l` but it doesn't work. In fact `Mod1+l` simply change focus of my window to another window.

Comment: according to following post it should work, but it doesn't: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150528/custom-shortcut-to-i3lock-screen  Yes, I tried adding `Control` as suggested there.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out in addition to having the `~/.i3/config` file, I also had a `~/.config/i3/config` file. So even though I was editing `~/.i3/config`, the system was not seeing my changes. So I went ahead and deleted `~/.config/i3/config`. Now it works fine.